# *-homomorphism between C*-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be C*-algebras. Let $\phi:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow M_2\mathcal{(B)}$ be *-homomorphism and 
>   $$\phi=\begin{bmatrix}
> \phi_{11} & \phi_{12}\\
> \phi_{21} & \phi_{22}
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   If $\phi_{11}:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow M(\mathcal{B})$ is a *-homomorphism is it true that $\phi_{12}=\phi_{21}=0$ and $\phi_{22}$ is a *-homomorphism?

Using $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ I got

$\phi_{11}(a)\phi_{21}(b)=0$

$\phi_{12}(ab)=\phi_{11}(a)\phi_{12}(b)+\phi_{12}(a)\phi_{22}(b)$

$\phi_{21}(ab)=\phi_{21}(a)\phi_{11}(b)+\phi_{22}(a)\phi_{21}(b)$

$\phi_{22}(ab)=\phi_{21}(a)\phi_{12}(b)+\phi_{22}(a)\phi_{22}(b)$

I could not conclude anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the 1,1 entries of $\phi(a^*a)$ and $\phi(a)^*\phi(a)$, you get (after using the $\phi_{11}$ is a $*$-homomorphism) that $\phi_{21}(a)^*\phi_{21}(a)=0$. So $\phi_{21}(a)=0$ for all $a$.

Now use that $\phi$ preserves adjoints to get that $\phi_{12}=0$. And now your last equation gives you that $\phi_{22}$ is multiplicative.